# Specify dependency version in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, dependencies, nuget

Is there a way to make a UWP app use a specific version of `System.Core` DLL (namely, the 4.0 version instead of 4.6)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to specify version of `System.Core`, It is consistent with the SDK version. The 4.0 version `System.Core` that you mentioned can only be used in the `NETFramework` rather than `.netcore`. I saw the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46478087/using-roslyn-scripting-in-uwp) about `System.Core` that you posted, and it looks like solved.